# Why dictionary printing the data before storing it?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, datastore

```
import random
import time

#2 Dictionary
a = {"A" : {"Result" : "N", "Time" : "N"}, "B" : {"Result" : "N", "Time" : "N"}, "C" : {"Result" : "N", "Time" : "N"}, "D" : {"Result" : "N", "Time" : "N"}}
b = {"A" : {"Result" : "N", "Time" : "N"}, "B" : {"Result" : "N", "Time" : "N"}, "C" : {"Result" : "N", "Time" : "N"}, "D" : {"Result" : "N", "Time" : "N"}}

def x(name, a1):
    v = random.choice(["Yes", "No", "Both", "Yes", "No", "Both", "Yes", "No", "Both", "Yes", "No", "Both"])
    if v == "Yes":
        a[name]["Result"] = "Yes"
        a[name]["Time"] = "5"
    elif v == "No":
        a[name]["Result"] = "No"
        a[name]["Time"] = "5"
    else:
        a[name]["Result"] = "N"
        a[name]["Time"] = "N"
    
    time.sleep(1)

while True:
    #Storing the current data on dict1
    x("A", a)
    x("B", a)
    x("C", a)
    x("D", a)
    
    for i in b.keys():
        #Printing the previously stored data on dict2.
        if b[i]["Result"] == "Yes":
            print("Yes")
        elif b[i]["Result"] == "No":
            print("No")
        else:
            print("N")
    
    #Storing the current dict1 data on dict2
    b = a
    time.sleep(30)
```

Here i am expecting while loop starts then stores the current data on dict `a` then its printing the dict `b` data then dict `a` data stored on dict `b` Then again loop restarts storing the current data on dict `a` then printing the past data stored on dict `b` then again stores the current dict `a` data on dict `b` . And it continues

But i dont know why during printing dict `b` past data its printing the current data that haven't stored yet on the dict `b`

Please help if anyone know

Answer (score 1):

At the end of each loop, `b = a` means you (re)alias `b` to the `dict` referred to by `a`; it's not a *copy*, it's just saying "whatever object `a` currently refers to, make `b` refer to it as well (whatever was in `b` before is irrelevant)". You never reassign `a`, so after that first aliasing, they're two names that both refer to the *same* `dict`; changes made through `a` are seen on `b` and vice-versa.

If you want to *snapshot* `a` into `b` (making a shallow copy), change:

```
b = a
```

to:

```
b = a.copy()
```

Given the values of the `dict`s are themselves mutable though, you probably need to deep copy, adding `import copy` to the top of your script and instead using:

```
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

To simplify the code, you might want to remove the original definition of `b` entirely, and move `b = copy.deepcopy(a)` to the *top* of the loop; `b` is only backing up the state of `a`, and duplicating the definition up top is pointless when you can just unconditionally back up the state before you begin modifying it each time (this assumes you never have a case where the `while` loop exits, after `a` is modified, before `b` is updated, where you'd want `b` to be updated; in the current code it doesn't matter, but it might in "real" code, so it's a judgement call).

---

As a side-note: Your code only works at all because you're relying on globals being visible in your function. The function should only be operating on its arguments, so each use of `a` in `x` should be using `a1` instead; this won't affect behavior in this case, but if this code were used elsewhere, and a different `dict` were passed in, the function would ignore it and continue mutating the global `a` where it was defined.